# How to prevent mobile view from loading in webview

Tags: android, webview

Am designing an android app with webview but always when the mobile view of the  website loads but i want to load the desktop version instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
WebView.getSettings()
.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
```

UserAgent strings for `setUserAgentString` method can be found here http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php