# WebView automatic redirect original URL to another URL

Tags: android, webview

I am using `Webview` to load URL in my application. Some URL is not loading page in `webview` and show message Webview not available. After debugging found that I am loading URL format like http://mywebdomain.com but in `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`  method of webclient when i am printing URL they print in following format http://m.mywebdomain.com. On IOS device it is loading page. 
How can I resolve this problem?? Please suggest..
Below is my code

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (view.getHitTestResult().getType() > 0) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);

        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);

        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(TAG, failingUrl + "Error: " + description);
            //view.loadData(errorData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            isLoadingError = true;
            if(utilityClass.checkInternetConnection()){
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvErrorMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvErrorMsg.setText(getString(R.string.noContentAvailable));
            }else
                showErrorDialog();

        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(webUrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to comment yet, so I must use Answer instead. Try solution from this question, maybe it would help in your case.
[How to prevent mobile view from loading in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934052/how-to-prevent-mobile-view-from-loading-in-webview)